# Long running file generation on Heroku + Django

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django app running on Heroku. The user can download various reports in either Excel/PDF format. Some of these reports can take a minute to generate, which means I need to create them on a background/worker process. I already have celery setup together with redis as the message broker.

My question is what is the best way to deal with this? This is my idea so far.

1. As soon as the user start the report, it shows 'Generating, please wait' on the page somewhere.
2. The file then gets generation and saved in a temporary location. Probably on S3 or in some sort of cache.
3. I then poll a specific location and once the file is ready it returns the url of where the file is stored. At this point the 'Please wait' turns into a link.
4. Once a day I clear out the S3 bucket using lifecycle rules

I'm sure this will work, but it just seems like a lot of effort and not the best user experience either. Currently the user just waits for the file once ready the download dialog appears. This works fine as long as the file is returned within 30 seconds, which isn't always the case.

I've also thought about emailing the file to the user, but I don't think this is a great approach.

Does anybody have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly not use e-mail.

With that out of the way, I don't see what's wrong with your approach from a UX perspective. Waiting for a file to be generated certainly beats timing out or waiting for 30 seconds before download starts, for that matter.

Depending on the use case, you could (a) provide an estimated time till the report is generated (may not be possible) and/or (b) have the user land on a different page with report details (possibly [using the HTML5 history API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776567/uri-changes-without-reload) to make it seamless).

Comment: I agree the UX is fine. The approach is just a lot of work for something that is currently working 90% of the time. I was hoping there was an easier method to fix this...

Comment: @Johan you could increase the timeout on the server to something like 2 minutes? but the user will have no way of knowing whether it's working so they could potentially think it isn't working. I mean, what you're really running into is an inherent limitation that you can't really fix simply. the approach you laid out is very similar to e.g. https://cloudconvert.com/